# ¿Cómo enviar un mensaje de conexion a un usuario al conectarse usando laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

Quisiera enviar algún tipo de mensaje a través de un modal o algo así para indicarle a un usuario que ha iniciado sesión... La idea sería que solo muestre el mensaje al iniciar sesión... he logrado enviar un mensaje pero cada vez que refresco la pagina de inicio

Esta es mi función para iniciar sesión con sus dos diferentes roles

```
 public function redirectPath()
{
    if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){

        $bitacora = TblBitacora::create([
        'accion' => 'Inicio de Sesión Admin Exitoso',
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'ip' => \Request::ip(),
        ]);
        return '/';


    }elseif(Auth::user()->hasRole('atc')){

        $bitacora = TblBitacora::create([
        'accion' => 'Inicio de Sesión ATC Exitoso',
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'ip' => \Request::ip(),
        ]);  
        return '/atc';
}

}
```

Y en esta parte dejo el modal con el que he creado el mensaje... no necesariamente tiene que ser a través de un modal... pero si es usando un modal sería mejor

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('#mostrarmodal').modal('show');
});
</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="mostrarmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <h3><center>Sistema</center></h3>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
          <h4><center>¡Aviso!</center></h4>
          <center>Inicio de Sesión exitoso</center>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info">Continuar</a>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: el modal sale cada vez que refresco la pagina... solamente quiero que aparezca cuando inicio sesión con cualquiera de los dos roles que tengo

Comment: alguna idea amigo?

Comment: agrega un if verificando si la variable $_Session no está asignada entonces muestra el modal.

Comment: no tiene ningun tipo de condicion tu modal siempre se ejecuta debes poner un condicional para que solo se ejecute cuando inicias session ya sea por variables de session o solo si se envia datos atraves de post  lo muestre!

Comment: si ese es el problema... se que tiene que haber un condicional al iniciar sesion.. pero no se como sería la sintexis a través de laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en tu login controller sobrescribe el método authenticated y dentro de este dispara una sesión, de esta forma:

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
   Session::flash('welcome', 'Bienvenid@ '. $user->name);        
}
```

no olvides importar el facade de sesion en el controlador:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

luego en la vista puedes hacer lo siguiente para mostrar el modal solo cuando la llave de sesión este presente es decir cuando inicie sesión

```
@if(Session::has('welcome'))
    <script>
        $('#mostrarmodal').modal('show');
    </script>
@endif
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias amigo!!!